# App crashes when number of rows changes after reloading table

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my iOS app there is a view with a tableview inside. The table cells are loaded from a PHP file on a remote server. I have also put a NSTimer on the view controller  that should reload the data.

The cells contain information that may change on a time interval. That is working fine only if the number of cells doesn't change on a time interval. If a cell is added on a time interval, then the app crashes.

This is the code for the NSTimer:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(refrescar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And this is the code for the method `refrescar`:

```
- (void)refrescar {

    total_actual =0;
    total =0;
    [self viewDidLoad];


}
```

I have also tried with this one:

```
 - (void)refrescar {

        total_actual =0;
        total =0;
        [self.tableView reloadData];


    }
```

But the app crashes as with the other code with `[self viewDidLoad];`

Any help is welcome.

Error log:

```
2014-11-13 23:52:23.299 RestAppXXI[1552:607] -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb6068
2014-11-13 23:52:23.429 RestAppXXI[1552:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb6068'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00b6a1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x031588e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00c07243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00b5a50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00b5a0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x01fd2cc7 -[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:] + 57
    6   UIKit                               0x01fd2b13 -[UILabel textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:] + 85
    7   UIKit                               0x01fd662e -[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:] + 173
    8   UIKit                               0x01fd6751 -[UILabel intrinsicContentSize] + 91
    9   UIKit                               0x024b07ef -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _generateContentSizeConstraints] + 36
    10  UIKit                               0x024b0480 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _updateContentSizeConstraints] + 511
    11  UIKit                               0x024b67bf -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraints] + 110
    12  UIKit                               0x01fd6579 -[UILabel updateConstraints] + 189
    13  UIKit                               0x024b6058 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 239
    14  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    15  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    17  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    18  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    19  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    21  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    22  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    23  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    25  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    26  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    27  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    29  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    30  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    31  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    33  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    34  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    35  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    37  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    38  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    39  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    41  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    42  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    43  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    44  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    45  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    46  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    47  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    48  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    49  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    50  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    51  UIKit                               0x024b6157 __UIViewRecursionHelper + 40
    52  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0bc69 CFArrayApplyFunction + 57
    53  UIKit                               0x024b5ffc -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 147
    54  UIKit                               0x024b61d6 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPass:] + 122
    55  UIKit                               0x024aa878 __62-[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 43
    56  Foundation                          0x02f0b68c -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 107
    57  Foundation                          0x02d9b3c5 -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 48
    58  UIKit                               0x024aa590 -[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 225
    59  UIKit                               0x024aa467 -[UIWindow(UIConstraintBasedLayout) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 90
    60  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0316a82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    61  QuartzCore                          0x0171a45a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    62  QuartzCore                          0x0170e244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    63  QuartzCore                          0x0170e0b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    64  QuartzCore                          0x016747fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    65  QuartzCore                          0x01675b85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    66  QuartzCore                          0x01676258 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    67  CoreFoundation                      0x00b3236e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    68  CoreFoundation                      0x00b322bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    69  CoreFoundation                      0x00b10254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    70  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0f9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    71  CoreFoundation                      0x00b0f7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    72  GraphicsServices                    0x041945ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    73  GraphicsServices                    0x0419442b GSEventRun + 104
    74  UIKit                               0x01e18f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    75  RestAppXXI                          0x000305ed main + 141
    76  libdyld.dylib                       0x049eb6d9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: can you tell the error log after the crash?

Comment: @iHulk, yes, of course, please wait a moment and I will update my question including the error log.

Comment: @iHulk, I have included the error log in my question.

Comment: Which indicates this is nothing to do with the tableview (directly at least). Let me guess; you're using JSON?

Comment: From your error it is clear that you are using the length function to get the length of a string but the string is null. so please go through your code use break point and nslog before the line you are using length function and try to decode it, you will solve it bro.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I guess what is happening. When the view is loaded the first time, there is a variable received from the previous view controller, that is a param of the URL to call the JSON file, then after reloading the view with the timer, I guess the variable is lost and therefor the Null length error. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you just build a pull to refresh feature ?

Comment: @iHulk, please read my answer to trojanfoe, may be there is the source of the error.

Comment: @Zhang, would you tell me how to do it?

Comment: You will need to look at the JSON you are receiving. It's almost certainly sending null when you expect a string.

Comment: @trojanfoe, but why does the app crash only when the number of rows do change after reloading the view? If the content of a row changes,  but no row is added, the app doesn't crash.

Comment: Please apply a check if(theObject){[theObject length]} before using the length function ([theObject length]) on any object and it will work

Comment: @iHulk, there is no object to apply your proposal..

Comment: add exception breakpoint ( 'to add do this, press cmd + 7 -> click on bottom right plus button -> select first option'  )

by this u will get know which object throughs the exception.

Comment: @iHulk, thank you. I am doing it now.

Comment: @iHulk, I have found the error. When adding a new row from the server side, one of the fields was always empty.

Comment: It was clear from the exception that some string was not coming from the server. Good to hear that It helped.

Answer (score 0):

That is not relevant to your `UITableView`. That is most probably from a string you are trying to access, but it's `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

User exception break point to debug, you are calling length method on NSNull object

And why to use NSTimer, you can reload table after getting response from server

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I am using the NSTimer, because the showed data may change during the interval period..